# I want not to scroll the comtent of kivymd MDDropDownMenu

Tags: python, menu, kivy, dropdown, kivymd

I was trying to make a dropdown using kivymd. I was a able to make it.

I imported **MDDropDownMenu from kivymd.uix.menu** then used the **MDDropDownMenu (some arguments).open()**.

It works fine. But allows the user to scroll the content. That is the list items in it.

I want to stop the scrolling functionality. How to do that?

*Please me help...*